# Does a senator have jurisdiction over the FBI?

Tags: realism, hannibal

In the movie *Hannibal*, after agent Starling gets into trouble from killing five people in a drug bust out, she is invited to an internal FBI interview, when she is offered a chance to work with the 4th victim (Mason Verger) of Hannibal. In this interview, something below is mentioned:

- They are not powerful (rich) enough to own a senator but they can rent them from time to time.

This heavily implies that a senator puts string over FBI so that agent Starling is freed from any consequences of the drug shooting.

- Does a senator have any jurisdiction over FBI? I would imagine that would be abuse of power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does a senator have any jurisdiction over FBI? I would imagine that would be abuse of power.

### No they don't...and yes it is.

Senators have no *direct* control over the FBI which operates as part of the Department of Justice

> The Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) is the domestic intelligence and security service of the United States, and its principal federal law enforcement agency. **Operating under the jurisdiction of the United States Department of Justice**, the FBI is also a member of the U.S. Intelligence Community and reports to both the Attorney General and the Director of National Intelligence
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Bureau_of_Investigation)</sup>

However, it is possibly (certainly in fiction) subject to political **influence** as its budget and oversight can, and often are, overseen by Senate committees and so a senator can have a disproportionate amount of influence.

Essentially, if a senator chooses to ask the FBI for a "favour" there's a strong possibility it will be considered favourably.

---

[**The script**](https://sfy.ru/?script=hannibal2001) has this line

> ```
>    Who he called, I don't know.  Someone
>    higher up than anyone in that room with
>    you.  Maybe Representative Vollmer, who
>    Mason may not own, but does rent from
>    time to time.
> ```

What we find from the novel is that this Representative is actually a Congressman and, more important, *does* have influence on the Justice Department.

> Old Verger also left Mason a U.S. congressman and a member of the **House Judiciary Oversight Committee** who just couldn’t make ends meet without him.
>
> <sup>*Hannibal* - Thomas Harris</sup>

---

> The U.S. House Committee on the Judiciary, also called the House Judiciary Committee, is a standing committee of the United States House of Representatives. It is charged with overseeing the administration of justice within the federal courts, administrative agencies and Federal law enforcement entities
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Committee_on_the_Judiciary)</sup>